# Taxonomy view resulting content fields

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that lists a set of taxonomy terms. When the user clicks on one of the taxonomy terms  in the view it sends them to a results page showing a list of all the content types that have this taxonomy term. The problem is views made this results page without any options for me to change it. Right now it only shows the title field and a read more link. I would like to add more of the content types fields to the result. For example the content type has images One thing i would like to do is add the image field to that results page so each result has an image. How do you add fields to the views results page that is after the user clicks the term on the taxonomy view.

Current view shows a list of taxonomy terms. When user clicks on one of the taxonomy terms in the view it will send them to a page showing a list of content that are associated with that taxonomy term. I want to edit the list of content that is associated with the selection, not the list of taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 2):

By default the output at *taxonomy/term/%* (with % being the term ID) is a collection of teasers for nodes to which the term ID is assigned.

You can alter the teaser display for each content type by going to *Structure > Content types > [type] > Manage Display > Teaser*. This is the simplest method, but note that this will alter the teaser display for the content type site-wide, not just on the taxonomy term results page.

If you want to alter the overall display of the results and you don't want to alter the teaser output everywhere else, @ShawnCohen's answer is your best bet. Views provides some powerful options for customizing a result set, including *Relationships* (mentioned by @Screenack in the comments).

Comment: I'm still lost as to how I can change the display. Editing the teaser display would change it everywhere so that would not be the solution for my current site but maybe for another site. I'm looking for a way to edit the display of the data as it pertness for the results of the selection made on the view. I have looked at every setting on the view admin panel and see no way to change that part of the data being displayed. Do you have a video tutorial or some kind of photo showing what i should be looking for. should i be making a template in my theme for that view?

Answer (score 1):

The "results page" you're talking about is a display set up by the Taxonomy module.

Views allows you to override this display by going to the Views administration page (**/admin/structure/views**) and clicking **Enable** on the **Taxonomy term** view. From there you can edit the view and change the fields just as you can with your original taxonomy view.

Comment: That lets me change the display of the taxonomy on the view. That part i have perfect. But the view displays the taxonomy terms you can click on them to get another list of content types that have that taxonomy term that is the list i'm trying to edit. I don't see any settings for the field types for that display.

Comment: To access your content's fields that have the taxonomy term, you'll need to use "Relationships" For example, if you click "Add" under "Relationships" and use "Taxonomy term: Content with term" After doing so, you'll see the new content fields available for you to use.

Comment: Patrick, I'm not sure you understood what Shawn is describing. He is referring to the page located at *taxonomy/term/%* (with % being the term ID). It lists all content to which the tag is assigned. Is that not the "results page" you are trying to customize?

Comment: so is this a tmp.php file that i need to edit/create to do this?

Comment: Patrick, did you try going to the Views administration page and enabling the "Taxonomy term" view? There will be two separate views involved: yours, and this one. Yours lists the terms, "Taxonomy term" lists the nodes. Once you enable the Taxonomy term view (as Shawn suggested), you can edit it to your heart's content.

Comment: Here is an intro: http://www.webomelette.com/how-customize-taxonomy-term-page-drupal-7-views. Google "drupal 7 customize taxonomy term page views" and there's no shortage of results.

Comment: Now i see what your both talking about. There is a grayed out view in the view list that changes the output of the results of the first view. I will be testing this out to see if this is the solution. I see the name of it is "Taxonomy term"